# How to use dtos in pipes/interceptors etc

Tags: typescript, nestjs

Let's say I have a method on my controller that looks the following way:

```
    @Post('register')
    @UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)
    @UsePipes(...[
        new ValidationPipe({ whitelist: true, forbidNonWhitelisted: true }),
        LoginCodeValidationPipe,
    ])
    public async register(@Body() user: RegisterUserDto): Promise<User> {
        // register logic
    }
```

Here `LoginCodeValidationPipe` is a validation pipe. It looks like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginCodeValidationPipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(
        private readonly cacheService: CacheService,
    ) {}

    public async transform(loginInfo: LoginDto) {
        const loginCode: string = await this.cacheService.get(KeyConverter.phoneLoginCode(loginInfo.phone));
        if (loginCode === loginInfo.loginCode) {
            return loginInfo;
        } else {
            throw new HttpException('Error message', HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem roots from the fact that I want my pipes to be reusable and I believe they should be.

So, what is important here is that `LoginDto` has all the fields present in `RegisterUserDto` or more precise, `LoginDto` is a subclass of `RegisterUserDto`.

So the data that is passed into the pipe is of type `RegisterUserDto` (the type of the factual parameter) but the pipe's formal parameter is of a different type (`LoginDto`) which might be confusing cos the types don't seem to be related, at least it's not clear.

How best to avoid that?!

My suggestion:

If I pass the pipe a dto, the dto should implement a specific for this pipe interface (in this case something like `ILoginCodeValidation`). Next, the type of the pipe's formal parameter (`LoginDto` in this case) should also implement `ILoginCodeValidation`.

But what name should be chosen instead of `loginInfo` for the pipe's parameter? I think one could use generics here. But right now I can't seem to figure out how.